# Recover MySQL from ibdata and frm

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, recovery

My MySQL server refuses to start because of InnoDB corruption. After googling I'm able to start the server in recovery mode (--innodb_force_recovery=3 to 6 allow starting server) but when I try to make a mysqldump I optain an error when selecting a table.

```
2017-06-28 23:59:25 7f33945d7700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139859509212928 in file btr0pcur.cc line 432
InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_prev(next_page, mtr) == buf_block_get_page_no(btr_pcur_get_block(cursor))
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
22:59:25 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=2147483648
read_buffer_size=4194304
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 2756236 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x31adf10
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f33945d6e18 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8e45b5]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x668b64]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf500)[0x7f347e506500]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f347cfa78a5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f347cfa9085]
mysqld[0xa4f323]
mysqld[0x9f2544]
mysqld[0x9f549a]
mysqld[0x953dcc]
mysqld(_ZN7handler13ha_index_nextEPh+0x66)[0x5a8496]
mysqld[0x6c1b8c]
mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x179)[0x6c5ca9]
mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x3da)[0x6c4aaa]
mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_P10SQL_I_ListI8st_orderESB_S7_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x250)[0x7098f0]
mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP13select_resultm+0x1b7)[0x70a1a7]
mysqld[0x6e405d]
mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x16b7)[0x6e6ba7]
mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x3c8)[0x6ea428]
mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x13ce)[0x6eb88e]
mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0xcf)[0x6b748f]
mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x47)[0x6b75b7]
mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x12d)[0xb1c7fd]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7851)[0x7f347e4fe851]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f347d05d90d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f338c004f50): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

If I try to select with `LIMIT` the query gives results but without `LIMIT` the query crashes the server.

I have tried REPAIR TABLE, OPTIMIZE TABLE, DROP INDEX, ALTER TABLE ENGINE = InnoDB... nothing works.

So if someone has an idea on how can I recover my data, I would be grateful.

Comment: How much RAM?  Which engine are you using?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Thx for your response.
I have try with multiple different values for RAM and innodb_buffer_pool_size but the problem stay the same.
The engine is InnoDB